# Spree - showing subcategories only when category is selected

Tags: categories, taxonomy, spree

I'm new to Spree, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I found a way to get Spree to show subcategories on the left nav (setting config.max_level_in_taxons_menu = 4), but in this method, all subcategories show up all the time. See below:

[image]

In the above example, I only want to display the 'Shirts and T-Shirts' when 'Clothing' is selected.

I guess I would have to edit the taxons_tree function in the base_helper.rb file, but I have no idea where to start.

```
def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
  return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.children.empty?
  content_tag :ul do
    root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
      css_class = (current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)) ? 'active' : nil
      content_tag :li, class: css_class do
       link_to(taxon.name, seo_url(taxon), "class" => css_class) +
       taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)
      end
    end.join("\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK - I guess while writing out the question, it got the cogs working in the brain, and I figured it out:

```
def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1, current_level = 1)
  return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.children.empty?
  if current_level == 1
    content_tag :ul, class: 'widget-shadow', id: 'left-nav' do
      root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
        css_class = (current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)) ? 'active' : nil
        content_tag :li, class: css_class do
          link_to(taxon.name, seo_url(taxon), "class" => css_class) +
          if current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)
            taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1, current_level + 1)
          end
        end
      end.join("\n").html_safe
    end
  else
    content_tag :ul do
      root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
        css_class = (current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)) ? 'active' : nil
        content_tag :li, class: css_class do
          link_to(taxon.name, seo_url(taxon), "class" => css_class) +
          if current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)
            taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1, current_level + 1)
          end
        end
      end.join("\n").html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

I had to make a different modification at the same time (root-level ul had to have id and class associated with it). There was probably an easier way to do it, but it works!

Anyway, I just used the same if statement that decided whether the li should be active to decide whether to recursively call the taxons_tree function.

I thought I would leave the question here anyway. Just in case someone else is an idiot like me.